# How to replicate this exact format in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode

[image: Equation required to replicate]

If anybody could assist in how to try replicating something like this in LaTeX it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\substack` for the formula and `mathtools` for the bracket numbering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newtagform{brackets}{[}{]}
\usetagform{brackets}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\substack{V_i\rightarrow1\\V_i\rightarrow0}\text{ if }\sum_{j\neq i}T_{ij}V_j\ \substack{>U_i\\<U_i}.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]